# How to fit whole item label on page?

Tags: itemize

I am writing a document with several long label texts. The problem is that they do not fit on this page, the text is too long and the left side gets cut.

This is the code I am using:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item [This text does not fit on page] Text
\end{itemize}
```

I am getting this result:

[image]

Is there any way to fit the whole label text on the page? It would be good if the label text would be split like this:

[image]

Comment: The `description` environment might be what you want to use.

Comment: Other than description, you can uuse  `\begin{itemize}[align=left]` (requires `enumitem`).